# Sharepoint Designer add time to date action

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, date-time

Is there any documentation on how SP adds time to a date? For example, if I add one month to today (say it's the 31st), does SP return the last day of the next month (the 30th)? What about leap years? I can't seem to find any info on this so if someone could point me in the right direction I'd appreciate it.

thanks.

Comment: I figured it out. I just created a test list with two date columns and a workflow to add time to a date value from the first date column. When I added one month to 1/31/2012 it returned 2/29/2012. When I added one month to the 15th, it returned the 15th of the next month.

Comment: Put your comment in as an answer then it can be marked as such

Comment: I had to wait ten hours before answering. I put it in the comments in case I forgot. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I just created a test list with two date columns and a workflow to add time to a date value. When I added one month to 1/31/2012 it returned 2/29/2012. When I added one month to the 15th, it returned the 15th of the next month.